# How do I iterate over subfolders for SCSS files to compile?

Tags: css, node.js, sass

I need to iterate over a subfolder for SCSS files in a variety of locations to compile in CSS (obviously). However, I have no idea how to do this, not being skilled in that area. I am also hampered by the fact I have to try to do this using NPM, and SASS (not node-sass).

Could someone give me a whistle-stop tour on how to achieve what I want?

It might also be worth pointing out that the SCSS files may reside in the SRC folder on the odd occasion, and I need to create the CSS files in the folder the SCSS was found in :(

As an example my folder structure looks a little like this;

```
Root
|
|- Components
|      |- src
|      |- styles
|           |- buttons.scss
|
|- package.json
```

The end result would look like this

```
Root
|
|- Components
|      |- src
|      |- styles
|           |- buttons.scss
|           |- buttons.css
|
|- package.json
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I would like to learn how to do this once and for all ;)

Comment: what do you use as a task manager/module bundler (as gulp or webpack)? you need to configure paths for sass transformer there as src/styles/**/*.scss

Comment: I'd have to say WebPack...